# Как написать условие для такого случая?

Tags: c#

Мне может приходить несколько видов строк, типу таких:

1. "SW"
2. "SW3"
3. "SW1W"
4. или же "SW1W 5" и до "SW1W 5NY"

Я не могу правильно логику подстроить таким образом, что если в строке есть символ "пробел"
и есть следующий символ(как я показал в 4 варианте) - сохранять(добавлять в бд) эту строку без пробела в конце.
А в противоположном случае => (если нет пробела и нет после нее никаких еще символов) то в конце строки добавить "пробел".

Мне потом нужно ее загнать инициализатор объекта:

```
Postcode = dal.Country == "GB" 
                            && dal.Point1PostCode.Length < 4
                                ? string.Concat(dal.PostCode, SpaceSymbol) 
                                : dal.PostCode,
```

Возможно есть другой и проще вариант. Это мой, к которому я дошел =(

Comment: Можно примеры на входе и выходе? Словесное описание мне не помогло понять задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задание не совсем ясное, но вот примерно код

```
string GetCorrected(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;
    int last = input.LastIndexOf(" ");
    if (last > -1 && last < input.Length-1) return input;
    else return input + " ";
}
```

Логика: если есть пробел и он не в конце слова - то ничего не делать, в противном случае добавить его в конец.

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(GetCorrected("SW").Replace(" ", "[SPACE]"));  
Console.WriteLine(GetCorrected("SW ").Replace(" ", "[SPACE]")); 
Console.WriteLine(GetCorrected("SW3").Replace(" ", "[SPACE]")); 
Console.WriteLine(GetCorrected("SW1W").Replace(" ", "[SPACE]"));    
Console.WriteLine(GetCorrected("SW1W 5").Replace(" ", "[SPACE]"));  
Console.WriteLine(GetCorrected("SW1W 5NY").Replace(" ", "[SPACE]"));
```

Вывод

```
SW[SPACE]
SW[SPACE][SPACE]
SW3[SPACE]
SW1W[SPACE]
SW1W[SPACE]5
SW1W[SPACE]5NY
```